# Como pegar os valores do inputs e colocá-los no respectivo elemento irmão

Tags: jquery, input, each

Resumidamente, minha marcação possui diversos elementos `form`, cada um possui uma `div` em si:

```
<form>
<div></div>
<input type=“hidden” value=“abc”>
</form>

<form>
<div></div>
<input type=“hidden” value=“def”>
</form>

<form>
<div></div>
<input type=“hidden” value=“ghi”>
</form>
```

A minha intenção é pegar o valor escrito do `input` e colocá-lo na sua **respectiva `div` irmã**, sem precisar ter de fazer um por um, pois o script iria ficar imenso.

Tentei de inúmeras formas, entre elas assim:

```
$('div').siblings('input').each( function () {
  var tst = $(this).val();
  $('div').text(tst);
});
```

Mas é colocado em todas as divs o valor do primeiro input.

Comment: não entendi bem James, o que dizer é que quer copiar por exemplo o input "abc" para os inputs "def" e "ghi" é isso? eu quer copiar o input para a div a seguir?

Comment: olá Ricardo, é copiar o valor do input para a div. A div vazia acima dele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta se encontrava na própria pergunta. Selecione os irmãos de um elemento com [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

```js
//Para cada elemento <input> que seja irmão de um div...
$('div').siblings('input').each(function() {
  var tst = $(this).val();                         //...obtém o valor desse input.
  $(this).siblings('div').first().text(tst);       //...atribui o valor desse input ao texto do seu primeiro irmão que seja um elemento <div>.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div></div>
  <input type="hidden" value="abc">
</form>

<form>
  <div></div>
  <input type="hidden" value="def">
</form>

<form>
  <div></div>
  <input type="hidden" value="ghi">
</form>
```

Comment: Compreendi! Muito obrigado pela explicação. Nesse começo muita coisa óbvia passa batida...

Comment: Augusto, tenho mais uma pequena dúvida... se o elemento cuja os valores dos inputs são mostrados seja "sobrinho" do input, ao invés de irmão dele, isto é, na verdade esteja dentro da div irmã, exemplo: <div class="elemento-irmão"><div class="aqui-vai-o-valor"></div></div><input type="text" value="o valor">. Como isso é expresso no jQuery?

Comment: Pelo que está escrito basta pegar o primeiro descendente do irmão que seja um `<div>` com [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/). Seria aproximadamente assim: `$(this).siblings('div').children('div').first().text(tst);`

Comment: Perfeito, entendi. Agradeço mais uma vez.

Comment: @Sam, `$("div:first-of-type", this).text($(":hidden", this).val());` o pseudo seletor `:first` foi depreciado. Sinalize como desnecessário após ler.